# Register and run PostgreSQL 9.0 as Windows Service

Tags: postgresql

For a while i have my db running on a command window because im not figuring out how to run it as a windows service.

Since i have the zip file version downloaded. how can i register the pg_ctl command as a windows service?

By the way, im using the following line to start the server:

```
"D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0.4/bin/pg_ctl.exe" -D "D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0.4/db_data" -l logfile start
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `register` parameter for the `pg_ctl` program.

The data directory should not be stored in `Program Files`, the location of `%ProgramData%` is e.g. a good choice.

```
pg_ctl.exe register -N PostgreSQL -U some_windows_username -P windows_password -D "%ProgramData%/db_data" ...
```

In newer versions of Postgres, a separate Windows account is no longer necessary, so the following is also sufficient

```
pg_ctl.exe register -N PostgreSQL -D "%ProgramData%/db_data" ...
```

Details are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html

You need to make sure the directory `D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0.4/db_data` has the correct privileges for the windows user you specify with the `-U` flag.

Btw: it is a bad idea to store program data in `Program Files`. You should move the data directory somewhere outside of `Program Files` because `Program Files` is usually highly restricted for regular users - with a very good reason.

Comment: That's exactly the plan =)

Comment: Be sure to execute this command from an elevated command prompt. (In other words, run cmd.exe as administrator.)

Answer (score 18):

Just run 'Command Prompt' as windows administrator and run the below command:

```
pg_ctl.exe register -N PostgreSQL -D "D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0.4/db_data"
```

You don't need to specify a User and Password, as previous answers have suggested.

Comment: Hi, nice first answer, perhaps you could add an extra newline character before `pg_ctl.exe register -N postgres -D "D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0.4/db_data"` as I can see you've tried to make it highlighted by adding 4 spaces before it.

Comment: I'm getting error while running above service in command prompt in windows system.

Comment: For Postgres 11 you'll want to modify the data location: `pg_ctl.exe register -N postgres -D "D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data"`