# How to install PostgreSQL on windows using command prompt?

Tags: windows, postgresql

Is there any way to install PostgreSQL on windows using command prompt?
 (Without using PostgreSQL installer)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
postgresql-9.3.3-1-windows-x64.exe --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --superpassword "password" --servicename "postgreSQL"
--servicepassword "password" --serverport 5432
```

Worth mentioning `postgresql-9.3.3-1-windows-x64.exe --help` will provide list of options and defaults which can be used.

Answer (score 16):

[Run the installer in unattended(silent) mode](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.3/pginstguide/PostgreSQL_Installation_Guide-12.htm#P345_22347)

-or-

[download the plain binaries](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload), `initdb` a new datadir, then start the server with `pg_ctl`. You can install a service with standard Windows tools like `sc` or can use `pg_ctl register` to create the service.

If you plan to bundle PostgreSQL in an application, *please* use the latter method (binary zip), *and* make sure you run it on a port other than the default port 5432 so your app doesn't conflict with any install the user might do themselves.

Comment: I exclusively use the ZIP distribution. Installing Postgres that way seems to be much faster (and easier - at least to me) compared to the installer

Comment: Yeah. I tend to use a mixture of the PGDG packages for Fedora, and source builds. The main benefit of using the Windows installer (on Windows) is that it'll get psqlODBC etc for you, but that's not overly hard to do manually.

Comment: One thing you might want to add: you can create the Windows service using `pg_ctl register ...`, you don't need `sc` for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am trying to use the same command. Its working . but the visual studio installer GUI is popping up and i am not able to see the pgadmin. But i can see that postgresql got installed in program files and the service is also there. Can you please help me out. I do not wish to have a gui to come up since i will be using with powershell(Invoke-command)

Comment: See [@a_horse_with_no_name answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14485121/1098603) for the syntax of `pg_ctl register ...`.